# Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client_New

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I've been reading about the error on the question title but I cannot figure out what is the error on my code below:

```
CREATE function [RPT].[MonthlyRollupDates_Delimited]()
RETURNS @table TABLE (Value varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN

Declare @Count int , @Date date = getdate(),@Month int
SET @Month = MONTH(@Date)
SET  @Count = @Month +12


Select 
top (@Count) 
CalendarDate,   BusinessDay, Label
from  MonthlyRollupDates
order by Calendardate desc

return
end
GO
```

The error I'm getting is

> Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a
>   client

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (MS SQL Server?)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put the results of your `SELECT`into your return table, and then return that table.

```
CREATE function [RPT].[MonthlyRollupDates_Delimited]()
--notice i modified the table to match the select statement, but assumed datatypes
RETURNS @table TABLE (CalendarDate datetime, BusinessDay int, Label char(10))
AS
BEGIN

declare @Count int
SET @Count = month(getdate()) + 12

--place your select into the table variable
insert into @table
Select top (@Count) 
    CalendarDate
    ,BusinessDay
    ,Label
from  
    MonthlyRollupDates
order by 
    Calendardate desc

return
end
GO
```

Comment: I did not know that I needed to put the column names and data types after the "Return @table" , I'll review the correct datatype based on the table where is getting them and update the script if needed. Thank you , I'll mark this question as resolve as soon as I test it :)

Comment: I'm sorry , I was able to test it a few minutes ago , there are too many business projects and university homework's :( .. Thank you :)